# Pandas: slice Dataframe according to values of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, import, slice

I have to slice my Dataframe according to values (imported from a txt) that occur in one of my Dataframe' s column. This is what I have:

```
>df
col1 col2
 a    1
 b    2
 c    3
 d    4

>'mytxt.txt'
2
3
```

This is what I need: drop rows whenever value in *col2* is not among values in *mytxt.txt*

Expected result must be:

```
>df
col1 col2
 b    2
 c    3
```

I tried:

```
values = pd.read_csv('mytxt.txt', header=None)
df = df.col2.isin(values)
```

But it doesn' t work. Help would be very appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read `values`, I would do it as a Series, and then convert it to a set, which will be more efficient for lookups:

```py
values = pd.read_csv('mytxt.txt', header=None, squeeze=True)
values = set(values.tolist())
```

Then slicing will work:

```py
>>> df[df.col2.isin(values)]
  col1  col2
1    b     2
2    c     3
```

What was happening is you were reading `values` in as a DataFrame rather than a Series, so the `.isin` method was not behaving as you expected.

Comment: Glad to hear it. If this solves your issue, please mark this as the accepted answer